# Setting file permissions for created files in R

Tags: r, file-permissions

I'm on Linux and want to share `R` output with co-workers while also allowing them to overwrite my files. However, when I write a file the permissions are set to read-only for the group, for example:

```
> write.csv(data.frame(a = 1:3), file = "/tmp/test.csv")
> file.mode("/tmp/test.csv")
[1] "644"
```

creates a file that is only writeable by myself. Is there some option I can set so that the files I write have permission `660` set automatically for all ways of writing files (`write.csv`, `data.table`, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to set the `umask` using `Sys.umask` as follows.

```
# Before setting umask as in the question:
> write.csv(data.frame(a = 1:3), file = "/tmp/test.csv")
> file.mode("/tmp/test.csv")
[1] "644"
# Setting the umask results in succes:
Sys.umask("006")
> write.csv(data.frame(a = 1:3), file = "/tmp/test2.csv")
> file.mode("/tmp/test2.csv")
[1] "660"
```